# What's an easy way to count reversal points of a dataset?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset ('db') with some reversal points. I would like to implement a counter ('counter_vals') starting at 0 that increases at each reversal point. How can I compute these counter values correctly in a simple way?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

db = np.array([12, 0, 6, 3, 0, -3, -6, -3, -6])
x_vals = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

plt.scatter(x_vals, db)
plt.plot(x_vals, db)
plt.show()
```

The desired output should like

```
counter_vals = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4])
```

Comment: what is a "reversal"

Comment: a reversal is a point after that the direction of a slope changes, i.e. from minus to plus

Answer (score 0):

You might use the derivatives. *"a point after that the direction of a slope changes"* is indicated by the second derivative. Due to numerical differentiations you will lose the boundary points (but you can improve that by adding a leading zero and by repeating the last element)

```
db = np.array([12, 0, 6, 3, 0, -3, -6, -3, -6])

deriv0 = np.diff(db)                              # first derivative
deriv1 = np.sign(np.diff(db))                     # signs of first derivative

deriv2 = np.sign(np.diff(deriv1))                 # signs of second derivative
deriv3 = np.abs(np.sign(np.diff(deriv1)) )        # absolute value of signs of second derivative

counter_vals = np.cumsum(deriv3)

print("deriv0 =", deriv0)
print("deriv1 =", deriv1)
print("deriv2 =", deriv2)
print("deriv3 =", deriv3)
print()
print("counter_vals =", counter_vals)


deriv0 = [-12   6  -3  -3  -3  -3   3  -3]
deriv1 = [-1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1]
deriv2 = [ 1 -1  0  0  0  1 -1]
deriv3 = [1 1 0 0 0 1 1]

counter_vals = [1 2 2 2 2 3 4]
```